# Sliding Tabs doesnt load correctly on second time

Tags: android, google-maps, pagerslidingtabstrip

Im using Google SlidingTabLayout with SlidingTabStrip.within a Fragment.
The fragment host 2 other fragments, one with a map view and other with a listview.
If I call this fragment from within a navigation drawer for the first time (open app) it correctly displays the fragment with the 2 tabs.

But when I try to return via the navigation drawer or via the back button, the fragment doesn't load anything, only a grey background like the slidinglayout didnt load correctly.

Can anyone point what am I doing wrong?

StoreTabHostFragment.java

```
public class StoreTabHostFragment extends Fragment {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private StoresPagerAdapter mAdapter;
    private SlidingTabLayout tabLayout;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_stores, container, false);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mAdapter = new StoresPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        tabLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.setDistributeEvenly(true);
        tabLayout.setViewPager(viewPager);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

StoreMapFragment.java (omitted some functions)

```
public class StoreMapFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener,OnMapReadyCallback {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private Bundle mBundle = new Bundle();
    private Double currentLng = -99.274643;
    private Double currentLat = 19.360460;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;
    private CameraPosition cameraPosition;
    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mBundle = savedInstanceState;
        sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, final ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_map, container, false);
        try{
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mMapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
        mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
        //setUpMapIfNeeded(rootView);
        return rootView;
    }
    private void addMarker(GoogleMap map, MFinderStore store){
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(Double.valueOf(store.lat), Double.valueOf(store.lng)))
                .title(store.storeName)
                .snippet(store.storeAddress)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.map_marker)));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLng)).title(getString(R.string.your_position)));
        cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(currentLat, currentLng)).zoom(14).build();
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
        getStoreList(googleMap);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
        //cameraPosition = mMap.getCameraPosition();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

StorePagerAdapter.java

```
public class StoresPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private static int FRAGMENT_NUMBER = 2;
    private Context context;
    private String tabTitles[] = new String[] {"Mapa", "Sucursales"};

    public StoresPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context){
        super(fm);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index){
        switch(index){
            case 0:
                return new StoreMapFragment();
            case 1:
                return new StoreListFragment();
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // get item count - equal to number of tabs
        return FRAGMENT_NUMBER;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position){
        return tabTitles[position];
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use FragmentStatePagerAdapter instead of using FragmentPagerAdapter which will solve this issue

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentPagerAdapter`

This is best when navigating between sibling screens representing a fixed, small number of pages.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`

This is best for paging across a collection of objects for which the number of pages is undetermined. It destroys fragments as the user navigates to other pages, minimizing memory usage.

To solve your problem, use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`